# How to prevent leaks from this angular6 rxjs 6

Tags: angular

I have the following function, in my authService.ts

It works but the subscription leaks. It's in a service that's used throughout the app on almost every component.

```
   mouseEvents:  Subscription;
    timer: Subscription;

    constructor() {
      if(user){
        this.updateOnIdle(user.uid);
      }
    }

private updateOnIdle(userId) {
  this.mouseEvents =  fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
                       .pipe(
                        throttleTime(2000)
                      )
                      .subscribe(() => {
                        firebase.database().ref('/status/' + userId).set({
                          status: 'online',
                          last_changed: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                      });
                        this.resetTimer(userId)
                     });
}

/// Reset the timer
private resetTimer(userId) {
  if (this.timer) {this.timer.unsubscribe()}

  this.timer = timer(5000)
                  .map(() => {
                    firebase.database().ref('/status/' + userId).set({
                      status: 'away',
                      last_changed: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                  });
                  }).subscribe();
}
```

How do I solve this? What would be the better way to write the functions?

Answer (score 2):

One solution to your leaky problem is to not use subscriptions in your `ts` but rather to return observables and let angular's `async` pipe manage subscription for you.

```
mouseEvents$:  Observable<any>;
timer$: Observable<any>;

constructor() {
  if(user){
    this.updateOnIdle(user.uid);
  }
}

private updateOnIdle(userId) {
  this.timer$ =  fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
                       .pipe(
                        throttleTime(2000),
                        switchMap(() => firebase.database().ref(`/status/${userId}`).set({status: 'online', last_changes: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP}),
                        map(your reset timer logic here)
                      );
                        this.resetTimer(userId);
                     });
}
```

Then in the html where you use it.

```
<div class="myTimer" [time]="timer$ | async"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, I don't need it in the html. Just to update the database.

Comment: If you need to update the db, you can just unsubscribe after the db update.

Comment: Thanks. But where will I fit the unsubscribe() method above in your answer? Am struggling with rxjs

Comment: You would just tack on `.unsubscribe()` after the `pipe()`

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of unsubscribing from an Observable, you could call the unsubscribe method, you can also use one of the operators that unsubscribe automatically :

- first : will complete and unsubscribe after the first fire.
- take : will complete and unsubscribe after n fires.
- takeUntil : will complete and unsubscribe when the passed Observable fires.
- takeWhile : will complete and unsubscribe when the condition is not true anymore.
- ...

You can choose the right operator for you case.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this question after answering your later question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744593/how-to-write-an-observable-that-unsubscribes-itself-rxjs6-angular6). I can now see the bigger picture and why you have no `subscribe()` calls in the other question.

Essentially, by 'leaking' I think you mean that the mouse events continue to fire after the components using the service have been destroyed?

If so, then the way to handle it may be to count references inside the service and `unsubscribe()` when the last one stops. Something like,

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  mouseEvents:  Subscription;
  timer: Subscription;
  refs = 0;

  constructor() {
  }

  public start() {
    if (!refs) {
      this.updateOnIdle(user.uid);
    }
    refs += 1;
  }

  public stop() {
    refs -= 1;
    if (!refs) {
      mouseEvents.unsubscribe();
      timer.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  private updateOnIdle(userId) {
    ...
  }
```

In the components,

```js
@Component()
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    private myService: MyService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    myService.start();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    myService.stop();
  }
```